# Odd behavior with Json when inheriting

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I've run into a type of issue.

I have an ErrorModel class, bare bones, that was inheriting ICollection.

```
public class ErrorsModel : ICollection<string>
    {
        private ICollection<string> Errors { get; set; }
        public bool HasErrors { get { return Errors != null && Errors.Any(); } }
        public string PartialView { get; set; }
}
```

Omitted the ICollection imp. as it is standard

When Returned by a controllers Action Json method

```
return Json(Errors)
```

The result is the private Errors object

```
[
  "Select a Country",
  "Select a City"
]
```

However when you remove the inheritance you get a complete serialization of the object.

```
{
"Count": 2,
  "HasErrors": true,
  "IsReadOnly": false
}
```

So my question is what is causing the odd serialization behavior when inheriting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON serializer is treating all collection classes as arrays.

JSON does not support mixtures of arrays and objects.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but when I make the private collection public without inheriting it also serializes correctly and shows both the properties and the collection.

Comment: @SCFi: Yes; that's a normal property that happens to be a collection.  What is your question?

Comment: Not a thing was misunderstanding the scope of mixture. Thank You